# Using a function returning a dataframe in R apply function

Tags: r

I got a list of files containing the same xml structure and I have a function, parsing this structure into a dataframe. In pseudocode, what I want to do is the following:

```
listOfFiles listFiles(diretoryPath)
foreach file in listOfFiles
   parse file to dataFrame 
   and add dataFrame to listOfDataFrames
combine listOfDataFrames to one dataframe
```

My first approach looked like this:

```
files<-list.files(path,full.names = TRUE)
dataFrames<-sapply(files,function(file){[...]return dataframe})
finalDataFrame<- rbind(dataFrames)
```

Which didn't work, since sapply returns a large matrix and not a list of dataframes.

Any good ideas how to do this elegantly in R?

Comment: Use lapply instead of sapply.  Adding the parameter simplify=FALSE in the call to sapply might work too but using lapply would just be the better route.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with elegant ways to parse XML.  We could use a bit more info about the problem

Comment: using lapply doesn't help: I still get a large matrix instead of a list of dataframes.

Comment: Where's your code? There are specific functions  in the XML package to handle these situations.  One cannot simply parse xml with `sapply()`

Comment: I have replaced the actual parsing code by the placeholder [...] in my example since the parsing function works and I don't think its relevant for this particular problem. The function could be any function returning a dataframe with the same column number and column names.

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Otherwise your problem is impossible to diagnose.